# Relative element overlaps earlier absolute element

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm having trouble positioning elements using tailwind. I currently have a submenu positioned absolute. Beneath this element, I have a search bar, who's parent is positioned relative, and the element itself is positioned absolute. This is so that the search icon can ble displayed in the middle of the input.

When the submenu is open, the search bar overlaps the submenu.

## Image

[image]

## Already tried

I've tried positioning the elements in another way, switching between the different positions. I've also tried setting z-indexes to the elements in question.

## Html

```
    <div>
        <nav>
            <!-- other navbar code -->
            <div class="block">
                <div class="hidden sm:block">
                    <a href="#" class="flex items-center font-medium text-base text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900 sm:mt-0 sm:text-xs sm:block">
                        <svg class="h-5 mr-2 fill-current h-5 mr-2 fill-current sm:block sm:m-auto" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                            <!-- path -->
                        </svg>
                        Name
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="sm:absolute sm:right-0 sm:mr-5 sm:bg-white sm:rounded sm:shadow"> <!-- needs to be absolute to not mess ut rest of navbar -->
                    <div class="border-t border-gray-300 sm:border-none">
                        <div class="px-5 py-5">
                            <span class="text-xs uppercase tracking-wider text-gray-500 font-semibold">Daniel Kjellid</span>
                            <a href="#" class="block mt-2 text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900">Action</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="border-t border-gray-300">
                        <div class="px-5 py-5">
                            <span class="text-xs uppercase tracking-wider text-gray-500 font-semibold">Administrator</span>
                            <a href="#" class="block mt-2 text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900">Another action</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="w-full text-center py-4 text-gray-900 font-medium bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-300">
                        Logg ut
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-white px-5 py-3 flex justify-between items-center border-b border-gray-300">
        <div class="relative mr-3 w-full"> <!-- needs to be relative to position svg inside input -->
            <div class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center pl-3">
                <svg class="h-6 w-6 fill-current text-gray-500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <!-- path -->
                </svg>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-input pl-10 py-2 rounded-lg bg-gray-300 text-gray-600 block w-full" placeholder="Søk blant hundrevis av varer">
        </div>
        <button class="open-filter-btn bg-gray-300 py-2 px-4 rounded-lg text-gray-600 flex items-center font-medium" type="button">
            <svg class="filter-closed-icn h-5 w-5 fill-current mr-2" viewBox="0 0 18 14" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <!-- path -->
            </svg>
            <svg class="filter-open-icn h-6 fill-current text-gray-600 hidden" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <!-- path -->
            </svg>       
            Filter
        </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: While I commend you for sharing the HTML I need to ask that you also share the relevant CSS - preferably setup as a "[Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)" that replicates the issue. Right now we can only make educated guesses.

Comment: Thank you for the super quick reply. I figured as the tailwind framework is utility based, it would not be necessary. Each class represents a single selector. So the class `flex` is equal to `display: flex;`, `absolute` is equal to `position: absolute;` and so on. If it still doesn't make sense, I'd be more then happy to collect them, but it would take some time...

Comment: I have the same issue. Tried z-index and doesn't work. It's really plaguing my project.